# UIScrollView contentOffset CoreMotion Bug

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm having a problem when I try to move the content of a UIScrollView with CoreMotion.

The thing is, I have a background with approximately 5000px, inside a container, which is inside my scrollView (is a landscape app); I already set the `self.scrollView.bounces = FALSE;`, my value for motion is `attitude.pitch * 10.0;` and when I move the content inside and it reaches the edge of the `pointZero` or the `self.scrollView.contentSize.width` it doesn't respect the bounds and keep moving in a white screen like it has no limit.

So, I set a verification (the code below), but when it reaches the `pointZero` it was supposed to stop but still give me a little white border.  I set a NSLog and I saw that the `contentOffset` was still going till `x =-14`, like the bounce was active.  The pitch value is controlling that because when the pitch value is zero the content stays at `pointZero`, when I raise the value of the pitch ir keep going till -14.

I think that is something wrong with my verification, if anyone can help I will be really grateful!!

```
self.accel = attitude.pitch *10.0;

//"pointZERO"----------------

if (self.gameArea.contentOffset.x <= self.gameArea.frame.origin.x) {
    NSLog(@"%2.f",self.gameArea.contentOffset.x);
    self.gameArea.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
 } else {
    self.gameArea.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.gameArea.contentOffset.x + self.accel,0.0);
}

 //"END OF SCREEN"------------------------

if (self.gameArea.contentOffset.x + self.gameArea.frame.size.width >= self.gameArea.contentSize.width) {
    NSLog(@"%2.f",self.gameArea.contentOffset.x);
    self.gameArea.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.gameArea.contentSize.width - self.gameArea.frame.size.width  ,0.0);
 } else {
    self.gameArea.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.gameArea.contentOffset.x + self.accel,0.0);
 }
```